# Cakephp 3 DebugKit

Tags: cakephp, debug

No CakePHP 2 eu costumo habilitar/desabilitar o DebubKit pelo AppController, de acordo com o usuário que está logado no sistema:

```
// AppController -> CakePHP 2
public function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
   ...
   if($this->usuario_logado_id > 1)
      Configure::write('debug', 0);
}
```

Porém, no CakePHP 3, o DebugKit é carregado do arquivo "Application.php"

```
// Application.php -> CakePHP 3
public function bootstrap(){
   parent::bootstrap();
   ...
   $this->addPlugin(\DebugKit\Plugin::class);
}
```

Existe alguma forma de desabilitar o DebubKit pelo AppController como faço no Cakephp 2 ?

Já tentei muitas formas diferente, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Você pode desabilitar no arquivo de configuração (config/app.php), setando a flag debug como false

Comment: Pelo que li na documentação, não é possível fazê-lo por uma controller, apenas pelo Application.php

Comment: O problema de desabilitar pelo app.php é que deve ser manual.
No Cakephp2 eu habilito para mim e deixo desabilitado para os demais usuários.

Comment: você utiliza o DebugKit ou somente o debug? O debug é possível ter seu valor dinâmico da forma que quer, já o debugkit não é possível

Comment: O debug eu consegui desabilitar dinamicamente...
O DebugKit não, as vezes é necessário utilizar ele.

Answer (score 0):

Você, programador, vai usar a aplicação em ambiente de desenvolvimento. Os demais usuários vão usá-la em ambiente de produção. A cópia que está na sua máquina deve ter o debug ativado. A cópia que está no servidor deve tê-lo desativado. Não se mistura isso, e também não se deve colocar esses arquivos no git. É mais seguro fazer via ftp.